# Prove $\mathrm{rank}(B^T B) = \mathrm{rank}(B) = \mathrm{rank}(B^T )$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

This is a very common fact used in various places, but as far as I know we can prove $\mathrm{rank}(B^TB) \leqslant \mathrm{rank}(B)$. How do we show the equality condition. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Suppose $\vec v$ is in the null space of $B^T B$. Then $B^T B \vec v = \vec 0$, and hence $\vec v^T \underbrace{B^T B \vec v}_{\vec 0} = (B\vec v)^T (B \vec v) = \| B \vec v \|^2 = 0$. This implies $B \vec v = \vec 0$ as well. Can you take it from here?

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the column space, which is the dimension of the image. Use rank-nullity and the above to conclude.